# Belongs_to and backup belongs_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This question comes from breaking up a question that was too big.

`Users` create `Events` as a `Role` in a `Network`. The `Events` are then connected to both the `Role` (different `Users` can occupy that `Role` when they are hired or fired) as well as the `Event`. `Users` that have administrative `Roles` can access all `Events` regardless of the `Role` that created the `Event`.

It is possible that `Role` could be destroyed, but the `Event` will persist as long as the `Network` exists. (Like if a position is deleted, but they still want the data for retired positions.)

So can the `Event` both `belongs_to` a `Role` and a `Network` separately? Is that bad rails design? Is there another way to do this? Would I have a special "Retired" role and keep events always tied to a `Role` and then use `belongs_to :network, :through => :role`?

Network.rb

```
class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, :through => :roles
  has_many :events
end
```

Role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :network
end
```

Event.rb - Is this right?

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role  
  belongs to :network
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it's not bad design with your associations (Events belonging to both Role and Network). And I think it's more confusing to have a "retired Role" than have it NULL. But perhaps you should consider having a column `status` on the Role rather than deleting it. If the status is not e.g. `1` (if 1 = ok and 2 = inactive as an example) it can't be used anymore, acting as it was deleted.

It's difficult to give an advice when you don't have the whole picture, but, as I said, in my opinion it's no need for a "retired" Role just to be able to change the associations.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose it's never bad to keep the data.